# PHP one form with two submit buttons and different validation

Tags: javascript, php

I have a single form with two submit buttons and there's a javascript validation in this form, is it possible to activate this validation only in one of my submit buttons? I tried to create an input button instead of input submit with an onclick event and then submit through javascript function, but it didn't work.

```
<form id="myform" action="my_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return IsValidForm();">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="auto" />
    <input type="submit" name="manual"/>
</form>
```

Comment: i think you could create a js function to submit data via ajax and then on clicking the button with validation you could first run the validation code then call the submit js function containing the ajax code and for other case directly call the submit js function

Comment: In my scenario I don't want ajax. I'm trying to figure out something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with moving the event handler to the submit button, you just shouldn't stop it being a submit button.

```
<form id="myform" action="my_action.php"
      method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="auto" onclick="return IsValidForm();">
    <input type="submit" name="manual">
</form>
```